# ajax request not working on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

```
function VReload()
{
     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "/foo/",
         success: function (data) {
        $("#myid").html(data);
        }
     });
 }
 $(document).ready(function() { 
setInterval('VReload()', 1000)
});
```

This piece of code is working fine on Mozilla and chrome but not on IE. Ajax call is not firing on IE. What could be the reason.

Comment: You are 100% sure it's the Ajax call that isn't being fired at all, as opposed to something else (like an Ajax error)?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What are the errors? Do you have a traceback from your console? What did Firebug have to say about it? Where are your `alert` calls that prove to you the flow of your code? What other debugging have you done so far?

Comment: Never pass a string as the first argument of `setInterval()`! In your case, simply pass `VReload` - if you need something with arguments, use `function() { /* your code here */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function VReload()
{
     var timestamp = new Date();
     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "/foo/" + "&timestamp=" + timestamp.getTime(),
         success: function (data) {
        $("#myid").html(data);
        }
     });
 }
 $(document).ready(function() { 
setInterval('VReload()', 1000)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Switch off caching by doing this:

```
$.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         cache: false,
         url: "/foo/",
         success: function (data) {
        $("#myid").html(data);
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 2):

set **cache false**

```
$.ajaxSetup({   cache: false    });
```

or

```
$.ajax({
         cache: false,
         //other options

     });
```

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery's $.get() function

```
$.get('/foo/', {}, function(data){
 // whatever
});
```

Comment: It's an nice way to simplify the code, but it's not an answer to the question